# What happens under the hood when I call a function which is virtual only in derived class

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
class Base {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "Base::foo" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "Derived::foo" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base* base = new Derived;
    base->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

This will call `Base::foo`. I am curios about on what is happening under the hood when having this code. I know that a table will be created for `Derived` that will contain a pointer to `foo` and also there is a pointer initialized by `Derived` constructor which will point to the table that contains the virtual functions.

So the result shows that static binding is happening, and I am curios how does this happens ?

I guess I am a little confused because if `Base::foo` were virtual then in `Derived` v-table `Base::foo` will have been overridden by `Dervied::foo` (which is the case now).

When compiling the code, does the compiler see that `Base::foo` is not virtual and performs static binding ? Is this the answer or is there another answer for this ?

Comment: What has that got to do with the hardware?

Comment: Hardware = under the hood

Comment: You can generate and read the assembly code, that's the closest anyone can get outside of being an actual chip-designer on Intel or AMD (or ARM or whatever architecture is used).

Comment: The answer to the question at the bottom of your post is *Yes* (non-virtual ==> static binding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call is resolved at compile time, just like any other call to a non-`virtual` function. Since the pointer is of type `Base*`, and the method in `Base` is not virtual, no lookup takes place, and it's basically translated to

```
base->Base::foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload resolution is done at compile-time, whether that results in a `virtual` or non-virtual function.
Code to call that unambiguous overload is then generated, which will use virtual dispatch if that's appropriate.

If you do it in the context of `Base`, the compiler does not know, nor care, that a later derived class may declare other functions with the same name; they are certainly not part of the overload set.